# Accessing a hash element that has a value of false specificially

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that i use in watir automation and it returns a true/false value based on the presence of elements in a UI. Rather than returning the entire hash, can i just return anything that evaluates to false?

```
     elements = {
      "Title" => @b.title == 'Details',
      "Name" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-name').present?,
      "Address" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-address').present?,
      "Stats" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-stats-container-top').present?,
      "Employee Information" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-stats-container').present?,
      "Reports" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-ribbon-container').present?
  }
  if elements.values.include? false
    puts "ERROR: Page Validation Failed. #{elements.inspect}"
    valid = false
  else
    valid = true
  end

  valid
```

Comment: Use WATIR tag if you raise any watir related questions!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write `elements = { "Title" => @b.title, "Name" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-name'),..., "Reports" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-ribbon-container') }` and then write, `elements.select { |k, v| (k == 'Title' and v != 'Details') || (k != 'Title' && v.present? == False) }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use select and return all values that are false

```rb
elements.select {|_key, value| !value }
```

your code would be like:

```rb
elements = {
  "Title" => @b.title == 'Details',
  "Name" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-name').present?,
  "Address" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-address').present?,
  "Stats" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-stats-container-top').present?,
  "Employee Information" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-stats-container').present?,
  "Reports" => @b.div(:class => 'rpt-ribbon-container').present?
}.select { |_key, value| !value }
```

Comment: Perfection, and i learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `Enumerable#reject` instead of using `Enumerable#select` with a negated condition. However, accessing a `Hash` by value is weird. It is also inefficient. In particular, a `Hash` with boolean values is isomorphic to a `Set`.

Comment: It may read better to write `value == False` rather than `!value`. The two are not quite equivalent but both work here (since `value` cannot equal `nil`).